I have a error on my code but I can't find it!
I have a problem by my code I can't find it yet!!
   (*Parameters*)
   aStart = 0;
   aEnd = 1.4;
   b = 0.3;
  nSteps = 10000;\[CapitalDelta]t = 0.001;\[Sigma] = 0.01;
  (*Noise intensity*)(*Initialize variables*)a = aStart;
   x = {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}; y = {0, 0};
   timeSeries = {};
  (*Generate time series*)

 For[n = 1, n <= nSteps, n++, a = aStart + (aEnd - aStart)*n*\[CapitalDelta]t;
   xNew = 1 - a x[[1]]^2 + b x[[2]] + \[Sigma] RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]; yNew = x[[1]] + \[Sigma] RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]; x = {xNew, yNew};AppendTo[timeSeries, x[[1]]];];
(*Plot time series*)
ListLinePlot[timeSeries, PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1.4}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
PlotLabel -> "x-Time Series for Stochastic", 
AxesLabel -> {"Time", "x"}, ImageSize -> Large]

I want to get this but not easy


Could you please elucidate what you expect to obtain, what the code produces and why you think it is in error. And what you did to find that error.

I want to get this plot!

I have a problem by my code the first obvious error I see is that you are using a For  loop  :)

What exactly are you trying to generate? It kind of looks like the plot you have there for the first 1000 steps or so but then it diverges.

Please write an informative title... one that relates to the content of your question.

This is the reference: Topological data analysis of financial time series: Landscapes of crashes Marian Gidea a,b, Yuri Katz c

I am finding that with delta-t set to .01 I tend to get overflows. When I set it to a tenth of that value it behaves. Try it like so: `aStart = 0;
aEnd = 1.4;
b = 0.3;
nSteps = 10000;
delt = 0.0001;
sig = 0.01;
a = aStart;
x = {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]};
timeSeries = Table[
a += (aEnd - aStart)*delt;
xNew =
1 - a  x[[1]]^2 + b  x[[2]] +
sig  RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
yNew = x[[1]] + sig  RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
x = {xNew, yNew};
x[[1]]
, {n, nSteps}];`

Turns out the code in the paper is also amiss. In the update for y they use x_n instead of x_{n+1}` (I found this by trial and error).

but Rangeplot is not the same??

No idea what Rangeplot might be. If you meant PlotRange then you need to take more seriously the use of proper termonology, uncluding case sensitivity. As it is, there were very obvious places where the code you showed departed from the description in the article. I have a sense that little or no debugging was attempted.

Corrected code is below. I chose a different sigma so that its product with the square root of the time delta would give a plot akin to the one in the article. I did not see where they set a value for sigma.
init[] := (aStart = 0;
  aEnd = 1.4;
  b = 0.3;
  delT = 0.001;
  nSteps = (aEnd - aStart)/delT;
  sigma = .1;
  a = aStart;
  sqrtdel = Sqrt[delT];
  {x, y} = RandomReal[1, 2];)

init[];

timeSeries = Table[
   x = 1 - a*x^2 + b*y + 
     sigma*sqrtdel*RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]; 
   y = x + sigma*sqrtdel*RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
   a += delt;
   x
   , {n, nSteps}];

To visualize in a manner like that of the paper:
ListLinePlot[timeSeries]


To get the picture in the paper we can change the y update.
init[];
timeSeries = Table[
   a += delt;
   xNew = 
    1 - a*x^2 + b*y + 
     sigma*sqrtdel*RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]; 
   yNew = x + sigma*sqrtdel*RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]; {x, 
     y} = {xNew, yNew};
   x
   , {n, nSteps}];

One visualization:
ListLinePlot[timeSeries]


Here is a cleaner way to see it:
ListPlot[timeSeries]



It's not working on my mac???
